# Greping specific text between quotation marks

Tags: linux, grep

I'm trying to grep specific fields from xml files and output them in a list. At the moment Im trying to use a grep like below:

`grep -E -o '.server name.{0,5}|.domain{0,10}.|.country.{0,15}' /dir/file.xml`

Since the country field name can be of varying lengths the 15 characters often captures other text I don't want. Is there a flag or option I can use so I only capture up to the next space? Or only text in between quotation marks following? Here is how the fields would appear in the xml...

`server name="Server1" mode="1" domain=".net" organisation="Org_1" country="United Kingdom"`

Comment: Maybe `grep -Po '(server name|domain|country)="\K[^"]+' /dir/file.xml`?

Comment: If you're working with XML, I'd suggest using a proper XML parser or xpath to extract your information.  There are so many variations possible with XML that your grep solution is going to be very fragile.   What if the name and mode fields are swapped?  That's valid XML, but your grep will not match.

Comment: [Please don't try to parse XML with regex. Use an XML parser instead.](//stackoverflow.com/a/1732454)